# Java Producer not recognizing property "Partitioner.class" property

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am running Cloudera provided Kafka version 0.9.0 and I have written a custom Producer

I am adding the following properties to my ProducerConfig:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
        props.put("acks", "all"); 
        //props.put("metadata.broker.list", this.getBrokers());
        //props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("partitioner.class", "com.vikas.MyPartitioner");
```

However when I am running my program, I am getting this error

```
16/08/23 18:00:33 INFO producer.ProducerConfig: ProducerConfig values:
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        block.on.buffer.full = true
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        batch.size = 16384
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        timeout.ms = 30000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        bootstrap.servers = [server01:9092, server02:9092]
        metric.reporters = []
        client.id =
        compression.type = none
        retries = 0
        max.request.size = 1048576
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        acks = all
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 10
        linger.ms = 1
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000

16/08/23 18:00:33 WARN producer.ProducerConfig: The configuration partitioner.class = null was supplied but isn't a known config.
```

As per the documentation on http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#producerconfigs

partitioner,class is a valid property but I am not sure why is kafka complaining about it being an unknown config.

Comment: Try passing it as a class value, not string: `props.put("partitioner.class", MyPartitioner.class)`

Comment: @serejja, The error says its not a known config.

Comment: @serejja, I tried the change you suggested but Still i am getting the same error

Comment: @VikasSaxena it says that the partition.class=null. Are you sure that it passes the class properly?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article http://www.javaworld.com/article/3066873/big-data/big-data-messaging-with-kafka-part-2.html it has sample on how to use custom partitioner.

As you can see the error message is

"16/08/23 18:00:33 WARN producer.ProducerConfig: The configuration partitioner.class = null was supplied but isn't a known config." which means Kafka does not understand the key **partitioner.class**

You might want to set partitioner like this

```
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG,"com.vikas.MyPartitioner");
```

Comment: As per the documentation on http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#producerconfigs

partitioner.class is a valid property but I am not sure why is kafka complaining about it being an unknown config. I will test the solution provided by you today.

Comment: Try this code article http://www.javaworld.com/article/3066873/big-data/big-data-messaging-with-kafka-part-2.html. It has section on custom partitioner. The sample code is in https://github.com/sdpatil/KafkaAPIClient/tree/master/src/main/java/com/spnotes/kafka/partition. Try com.spnotes.kafka.partition.Producer class it uses custom partitioner